# Netsuite: Double Sorting on Advance PDF

Tags: netsuite

I was looking a way to do double sorting on the picking slip. Our company has 3 departments on netsuite. I am looking to sort by Department 1st and within the department by item catageory.
Currently, it is only sorting by brand with the code:

```
<#list record.item?sort_by("cust_brand") as item>
```

how do I add to sort by item catageory as well after brand?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you cannot do multi-key sorting in Netsuite's version of Freemarker

What you can do is use the sequence built-ins and do your own grouping and sorting.

a bit more detail in code taken from a working example is here: [Does Oracle NetSuite Advanced PDF Template have "Group by" and "SUM" Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013395/does-oracle-netsuite-advanced-pdf-template-have-group-by-and-sum-functions/44030039#44030039)

A quick bit of code for your case might look like:

```
<#if record.item?has_content>
    <table class="itemtable" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;"><!-- start items -->
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th colspan="5">Style</th>
            <th align="left" colspan="11">Description</th>
            <th align="center" colspan="7">Size/Quantity</th>
            <th align="center" colspan="4">Unit Price</th>
            <th align="center" colspan="3">Quantity</th>
            
            </tr>
        </thead>


        <#assign depts = []>
        <#list record.item?sort_by("department")  as lineitem>
            <#assign item_dept = lineitem.department>
            <#if depts?seq_contains(item_dept)>
            <#else>
                <#assign depts = depts + [item_dept]>
            </#if>
        </#list>
        <#list depts?sort as dept>
            <#list record.item?sort_by("cust_brand")  as lineitem>
            <#if linteitem.department == dept>
                <tr>
                    ...
                </tr
            </#if>
        </#list>
    </table>
</#if>
```